# How to extract just the date from a DateTimeOffset object

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

How to extract just the date from a **DateTimeOffset** object? I thought the **Date** property would return just the date part. But, I keep getting the whole datetime, i.e. **7/17/2014 12:00:00 AM -04:00**. I'd like to get only the date portion **7/17/2014**.

Here's my code.

```
Func<DataRow, string, DateTimeOffset?> getFieldNullableDate = (row, field) =>
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((row[field] ?? string.Empty).ToString()))
      return DateTimeOffset.Parse(row[field].ToString()).Date;
  else
      return null;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the whole date"?  The Date property will return a DateTime object, with the time portion set to midnight.

Comment: `ToShortDateString` is the string representation formatted with "d" format. So just do `DateTimeOffset.ToString("d")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this to extract only `MM/DD/YYYY` from the `DateTimeOffset?` variable.

```
DateTimeOffset? testOne = null;

var final = testOne.HasValue ? testOne.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() : null;//null

DateTimeOffset? testTwo = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today);

var notNull = testTwo.HasValue 
            ? testTwo.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() 
            : null;// 7/24/2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually DateTimeOffSet object has Date and DateTime property that you can use :
example

```
DateTimeOffset? offset = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today);
var dateTime = offset.HasValue ? offset.Value.DateTime : DateTime.MinValue.Date;
var date = offset.HasValue ? offset.Value.Date : DateTime.MinValue.Date;
Console.WriteLine($"date time:{dateTime} and date:{date}");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the Time Information from DateTime**

```
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime datePart = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only the date part that represents the START of the current day just like `DateTime.Today` does:

```
var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;    // 2023-11-12T23:35:37.2256351+03:00
var today = now - now.TimeOfDay; // 2023-11-12T00:00:00.0000000+03:00
```

This will keep the offset and still be `DateTimeOffset` where `DateTimeOffset.Now.Date` will not because that returns a `DateTime`.

Answer (score -1):

I did not go through your code, but I believe you are looking for this method:

```
public string ToShortDateString()
```

Example:

```
DateTime thisDay = DateTime.Today;
thisday = thisday.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: He is using a DateTimeOffset not a DateTime. DateTimeOffset does not have the method ToShortDateString